# Where to configure my smtp server in Mutt utility

Tags: mutt, smtp

I have my smtp server -- smtp.drdb.com which is registered in DNS. I need to setup Mutt utility in my RHEL 6 server. Where should I input my smtp server details in mutt.rc file so that I can send mail. When I try to send mail from mutt, it goves me error Invalid URL - smtp.drdb.com

Answer (score 4):

If you use a version of mutt that is [compiled with SMTP support](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#smtp) then mutt can send mail to another server via SMTP. Otherwise it will always use the local mail server.

To use it, you have to set the `smtp_url`variable.

```
  smtp_url
          Type: string
          Default: “”

          Defines the SMTP smarthost where sent messages should relayed
          for delivery. This should take the form of an SMTP URL, e.g.:


          smtp[s]://[user[:pass]@]host[:port]


          where “[...]” denotes an optional part.  Setting this variable
          overrides the value of the $sendmail variable.
```

Comment: Where would one find the `smtp_url` - also the link is dead:( ?

Answer (score 4):

Just to complement the original answer - in order to set external SMTP server you need to add following line either to /etc/Muttrc (for system-wide configuration) or ~/.muttrc (for user configuration):

```
set smtp_url = "smtp[s]://[user[:pass]@]host[:port]"
```

where host is your SMTP server, and as said in the original answer everything inside [] is optional...

Comment: example: 
`set smtp_url = "smtp://gmailusername:password@smtp.gmail.com:587"`

Answer (score 1):

The actual sending of mail is traditionally delegated to an external program like `sendmail`, mutt does not connect to SMTP directly itself. If sendmail is too much for you, you can consider using something like `msmtp` for a simple delivery mechanism to an SMTP server, the actual SMTP server is then configured in a simple `~/.msmtprc` configuration. Consult the documentation (`man msmtp`).

Comment: Mutt is capable of connecting to an SMTP server.  See `smtp_url` as described in another answer.